# Why Can't I Make a Macally G-S350SUAB2 Boot Family's iMac?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, imac, startup

I can't seem to be able to get the Macally G-S350SUAB2 enclosure that my dad loaned me for development use to boot a copy of OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks which I installed using my dad's early- or late-2011 13.3-inch MacBook Pro (sorry, but I can't exactly remember which model it is…) from my family's mid-2007 24-inch iMac.  Near the bottom of its eleventh page, [the G-S350SUAB2's manual](http://www.macally.com/EN/techsupport/manual/G-S350SUAB2manualv1.pdf) states that OS X should recognize any drive installed inside its chassis as long as it has been 'initialized.'  I assume that 'initializing' the drive inside the enclosure would just mean formatting it.

I *did* format the drive inside the Macally G-350SUAB2 enclosure prior to having the MacBook Pro run the OS X Mavericks installer from a 'Recovery Mode' DVD which my Dad burned a little while back.  He was able to do this by burning the disk image at `/Volumes/InstallESD.dmg/Packages/BaseSystem.dmg` inside `/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg` to the then-blank DVD.  During the installation process, the code on the disc attempted to contact the App Store for the latest version of the Mavericks installer.  The attempt was successful due to the fact that I selected our WiFi network from a pop-up menu that appeared below the list of available boot drives that shows up when you hold down the 'Option' key during the boot process and had my dad enter its password.

The 'Recovery Mode' DVD then proceeded to download and run the OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks installer.  It successfully rebooted to finish the installation and prompt me to set up my first administrator account.  After responding to this prompt, I used this new administrator account to do some additional setup and download and install Xcode from the App Store, the 'Command Line Tools for Xcode (OS X Mavericks)' from Apple Developer Connection, and GitHub for Mac from GitHub.  After shutting down, I disconnected the Macally enclosure from both its power supply and the MacBook Pro and then lugged it upstairs to reconnect the former and connect it to the iMac which I mentioned earlier.  I held down the 'Option' key to get the boot-drive selection screen, but the drive inside the enclosure didn't show up!  What in the multiverse could be happening?!?

I know that OS X requires the drives hosting it to be formatted with the 'GUID Partition Map' and journaled HFS+, so I would have thought that this could mean either that the one-terabyte drive which my dad loaned me to use with this enclosure could have been incorrectly formatted or that I might be having some trouble with the enclosure's power supply just like somebody suggested someone else might have had quite a while back with a drive containing Mac OS X 10.5.8 Leopard in [this 'Apple Support Communities' discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2641720?start=0&tstart=0), but the drive inside the G-S350SUAB2 boots the MacBook Pro which I mentioned earlier without any trouble at all, so I know that this can't be true, so I'm stumped.  Does anybody have any ideas about what might be going on here…?

Comment: This is an interesting question but a wall of text is not the easiest to read and digest; some paragraphs may help a bit!

Comment: Hold on; let me work on splitting it up into multiple paragraphs…

Comment: OK; I'm done editing this question to make it more readable.  Would you or anybody else like to look at it again, @GeorgeGarside?

Comment: And thus the plot thickens:  I can get the drive to boot via USB on the iMac, but not via FireWire 800 like I can on the MacBook Pro.  Plus, that was _after_ I updated the Macally G-S350SUAB2 enclosure's firmware using the procedure described at the bottom of [this Macally support page](http://www.macally.com/EN/?page_id=23) (I thought it might fix my problem with booting even though it was only described as enabling the use of drives of capacities greater than three terabytes with the enclosure in question.   This just keeps getting stranger and stranger, doesn't it?